# Getting resource string value by Resource string identifier

Tags: delphi, resourcestring

How to get resource string value by Resource string identifier.

ResourceString
  MyString = 'ABC';

If I have string identifier for MyString, how to fetch value 'ABC' form that ID.

Comment: `S := MyString;` where `S` is a string variable. P.S. it's usual to prefix the resource string names by `rs`, in your case like `rsMyString`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29145598/33732

Comment: @Ken, I don't think it's a duplicate. I got it as that this is how to get value by identifier, how to get value `'ABC'` by `MyString` (though it's difficult to say if it's not about getting the resource value by resource identifier name at runtime when having an identifier string such as `'MyString'`).

Comment: I've just re-read this user's previous question, and I think you're right, @Tlama. The duplicate's function takes the string `'MyString'` and returns `'ABC'`, but the request here is for the opposite: Take either `'ABC'` or `PResStringRec(@MyString).Identifier` and return the string `'MyString'`.

Comment: @Rob: I read it differently, but you and TLama both think I made a mistake, so I've reversed the closure.

Comment: @TLama: See my note to Rob. :-)

Comment: Thanks All for your valuable comments, suppose ResourceString identifier is '64232' and  resource string value is 'ABC'. So I was trying to fetch resource string value i.e. 'ABC' for its identifier suppose ResourceString identifier is '64232'. I was searching for some built in method to do this but I have not found any.